# How to export custom data types from one Sybase DB and import to another?

Tags: t-sql, sybase

There are several hundred custom data types in a source Sybase DB need to be in a new, freshly created destination Sybase DB.

Through some fidgeting, I was able to create a script to extract and add all the custom data types from the source DB into the destination DB. However, I keep getting the following error:

`Number (257) Severity (16) State (1) Server (ASED052) Implicit conversion from datatype 'NUMERIC' to 'VARCHAR' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.`

I checked and double checked that all the types matched (though types of `CHAR` in source is made to be `VARCHAR` in destination, I think this is an OKAY implicit conversion?)

Is there a way to create a script that would allow me to export all custom data types from the source DB and import them into a destination DB such that the types will match and there will be no conversion issues?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the **ddlgen** utility included with sybase, ususally found in the Sybase Central directory, or the $SYBASE/ASEP/bin.  The syntax may vary slightly between Sybase versions, but you should be able to generate scripts to create all of the database objects including user-defined datatypes (UDD), indexes, stored procedures, etc.

If you only want the user-defined datatypes, look into the **"-T"** flag, which allows you to select specific object types.

Comment: Possibly.  The ddlgen binary is inside the Sybase installation, so you may have to work with the dba to get access to it.  It shouldn't cause much in the way of overhead, as it just queries system tables.  As far as permissions are concerned, I'm not sure, but I'll try to test it out when I get a chance.

Comment: I just tested, and I was able to pull table structure information as a regular user.  I don't have any user-defined data types to test with, but it appears to work for non-priveledged users.